# MS Access 2016 - Add 2 separate criteria behind Before Update event

Tags: vba, ms-access, beforeupdate

I have VBA code behind a form field to ensure that the parent record is created before the 'Discussed' field in the subform can be entered:

```
Private Sub Discussed_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If IsNull(Me.Parent.ID) Then
   MsgBox "You cannot save this record without entering the issue details", vbOKOnly
   Cancel = True
   Exit Sub
End If
'...
End Sub
```

This works fine but I also want to make sure that the same discussion date is NOT added against the same Issue ID so I have found this:

```
If DCount("*", "Discussed", "[Issue_ID]= " & Me.[Issue_ID] & " and [Discussed]= #" & Format(Me.[Discussed], "dd/mm/yyyy") & "#") > 0 Then
    MsgBox "You entered a duplicate date. Please try again.", vbInformation, "Duplicate Date!"
    Cancel = True
    Me.Discussed.Undo
    '...
End If
```

Am not sure how to add this criterion into the same sub as one criterion seems to cancel out the other - any advice would be greatly appreciated

Adding in second criteria did not do anything

Comment: Keep in mind that Access will ALWAYS execute a save of the main record when focus moves to the sub form. So, really, no extra code should be required, since with that automatic save when focus moves from main form to sub form, then the record will HAVE to exist, and thus you can assume the main record does exist. A relational database requires the parent record to exist, and this is why then Access performs the automatic save of the main record. This includes the case when the main form record is new. Once again, the save is automatic, and thus the main parent record will exist.

Comment: Maybe `ElseIf DCount ...`

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in your comments, it not really possible to move focus to the sub form without the parent form automatic saving the parent record. Not only is this a requirement for relational databases, it also why Access automatic executes a save for in the parent record when focus moves to the child form.

Thus, if you are somehow able to move to the child form, and enter data, then some details here are missing, since this in theory should not be possbile.

Comment: got this  - thanks. However I did want to keep the code in so that the message would come up to tell the user they haven't yet entered the main record. One thing I am struggling with is the If DCount("*", "Discussed", "[Issue_ID]= " & Me.[Issue_ID] & " and [Discussed]= #" & Format(Me.[Discussed], "dd/mm/yyyy") & "#") > 0 Then
    MsgBox "You entered a duplicate date. Please try again.", vbInformation, "Duplicate Date!"
    Cancel = True
    Me.Discussed.Undo
    '...
End If

Comment: - The Issues Table can have duplicate IDs as there can be many issues aligned to a service (Service table being the main table in the hierarchy). I cannot therefore set the 'No Duplicates' properties in the Issues table but I want to be sure that the same date cannot be entered against the same issue ID. The code I wrote does seem to flag up the warning but still lets the user keep a duplicate date. Is there something else I should be adding to the sub?

Comment: The issue of preventing duplicates is a huge Mount Everest of a different question, and different issue then that of ensuring the parent record is first saved.  If you don't want a duplicate date, then use the before update event of the date field on the sub form, and check if the date already exists in the database, and give message, and then set cancel = true in that date before update event. So, testing for some duplicate date is a vast different issue and question compared to that of ensuring the parent record is to exist first